# Matplotlib legend mis-aligned

Tags: matplotlib, legend

[image]

I am trying to plot a legend in Matplotlib, but for some reason the label is not aligned with the line description. Do you know why this happens? Code below:

````
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

fig=plt.figure(facecolor='white',figsize=sizefigs_L)

ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax=settings_plot(ax)

lm_space=[x for x in l_space]
lt_space=[tilde_l(x,L,df[0],A,xi) for x in l_space]

plt.plot(l_space,lm_space,ls='--',c='r',label=r'$\lambda_m$')
plt.plot(l_space,lt_space,ls='-',c='b',label=r'$\tilde{\lambda}$')

plt.scatter(L-xi,L-xi,marker='o',c='g',s=200)
plt.scatter(L+xi,L+xi,marker='o',c='g',s=200)

plt.scatter(lsol(L,df[0],A)[1],lsol(L,df[0],A)[1],marker='s',c='m',s=200)

plt.arrow(lsol(L,df[0],A)[1], lsol(L,df[0],A)[1]+0.15, 0.10, 0.075, width=0.005,head_width=0.03,
         fc='k', ec='k',length_includes_head=True)
plt.arrow(lsol(L,df[0],A)[1]-0.05, lsol(L,df[0],A)[1]+0.1, -0.10, -0.075, width=0.005,head_width=0.03,
         fc='k', ec='k',length_includes_head=True)


plt.legend(loc='best',frameon=False,fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel(r'Expectation of marginal investor ($\lambda_m$)',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(r'Reaction function $\tilde{\lambda}\left(\lambda_m\right)$',fontsize=16)

plt.title(r'Case (i): $\Delta f \leq \zeta \left(\Lambda-\xi\right)\xi$',fontsize=16)```
````

Comment: Your code is very incomplete. For example, what happens in `settings_plot(ax)`? Could you try to create a minimal example that can run standalone? Provide some dummy data for  `l_space`, `lm_space` and `lt_space`.  Leave out the `scatter` and the `arrow` plots (except if the problem would appear with them present and disappear when they're not).  Maybe your problem is due to some specific settings in which you're running the code?

Comment: I tracked it down to the LaTeX implementation: ```plt.rc('text', usetex=True)```. If I leave this out, then the legend looks OK, but the math font is not the one I want.

Comment: Maybe you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66250441/edit) your question, and only put the minimal code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem.  Are you running the latest version of matplotlib?

Comment: I eventually solved the main issue with: 
```from matplotlib import font_manager
font_manager._rebuild()```
but the code runs extremely slow on my Windows machine with TeX enabled. I just moved from a Mac where the same code ran in no time...